# Encoding URI query parameter with slash (without double encoding) and special characters in Java

Tags: java, encode, resttemplate, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

I have 2 string variables with sample input:

1. **content**: "m/=a"
2. **sms**: "TEST123 ~!@#$%^&*()_+{}:<>?"

I need to send these two variables as query params using GET method. Below is my code.

## Creating rest template:

```
DefaultUriBuilderFactory defaultUriBuilderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
defaultUriBuilderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);

RestTemplate restTemplate = constructRestTemplate(cpConnectivity);
restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(defaultUriBuilderFactory);
```

## Encode function:

```
return URLEncoder.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

## Sending request:

```
UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
.queryParam("content", encode(content)
.queryParam("sms", sms.replace(" ", "+"));

ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uriComponentsBuilder.build(false).toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class);
```

The expected query param values for those variables is:

**content**: "m%2F%3Da"

Special characters should be encoded, including slash (/).

**sms**: "TEST123+~!@%23$%25%5E%26*()_+%7B%7D:%3C%3E?"

Space should be replaced with + sign, reserved special characters should be encoded.

Using the **existing** code, **content** is encoded as expected, but **sms** cannot contain reserved special characters, otherwise it will give errors like "Illegal character in query at index 45:" and "Malformed escape pair at index 151: ".

I have tried other solutions:

- `uriComponentsBuilder.build(true).toUriString()`
- `uriComponentsBuilder.build(false).encode().toUriString()`
- `uriComponentsBuilder.build(true).encode().toUriString()`
- `uriComponentsBuilder.encode().toUriString()`
- `defaultUriBuilderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.TEMPLATE_AND_VALUES);`
- `defaultUriBuilderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY);`
- `defaultUriBuilderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.URI_COMPONENT);`
- `URLDecoder.decode` first then `encode()`

Without calling `encode()`, slash (/) will not be encoded, because it is a valid character. If I call `encode()`, the problem is % is double encoded, so slash (/) will be %252F. If I set `.build(true)`, I get errors like "Invalid character" or "Invalid encoded sequence".

Comment: “Space should be replaced with + sign”  No, it shouldn’t.  You are thinking of [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) content.  URI escaping never uses `+` represent space.  `%20` is the only correct way to represent an ASCII space.  java.net.URLEncoder is for submitting HTML form items, not for escaping characters in URIs.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, the business requirement is that the server expects space to be replaced with + sign, not %20.
Before sending the request using restTemplate, when I print the request, it is all good. But after sending, the request is either double encoded, or not encoded at all which causes malformed/invalid error.

Comment: In that case, perhaps you can forego URIComponentsBuilder, and just use `"content=" + URLEncoder.encode(content, UTF_8) + "&sms=" + URLEncoder.encode(sms, UTF_8)`?

Comment: Yes I think that could work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I need to send these two variables as query params using GET method. ..."*

Here is an example, which will encode all *non-alphanumerics*.

```java
String encode(String s) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray())
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') b.append(c);
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') b.append(c);
        else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') b.append(c);
        else b.append("%%%x".formatted((int) c));
    return b.toString();
}
```

```java
String decode(String s) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)%[a-f\\d]{2}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    char c;
    while (m.find()) {
        c = (char) Integer.parseInt(m.group().substring(1), 16);
        m.appendReplacement(b, Matcher.quoteReplacement(String.valueOf(c)));
    }
    m.appendTail(b);
    return b.toString();
}
```

And, here is an example usage.

```java
String s;
out.println(s = encode("TEST123 ~!@#$%^&*()_+{}:<>?"));
out.println(decode(s));
```

Output

```
TEST123%20%7e%21%40%23%24%25%5e%26%2a%28%29%5f%2b%7b%7d%3a%3c%3e%3f
TEST123 ~!@#$%^&*()_+{}:<>?
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How is it different from URLEncoder.encode() ?

Answer (score 0):

I still use the same rest template code and encode function. I adjusted the code when sending request to:

```
UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
.queryParam("content", "contentplaceholder")
.queryParam("sms", sms.replace(" ", "+"));

String url = uriComponentsBuilder.build().encode().toUriString();
url = url.replace("contentplaceholder", encode(request.getMsisdn()));
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class);
```

UriComponentsBuilder encodes the unsafe special characters. Then I manually encode the content param, then send the request.